# Need well formatted data for testing

Tags: string, csv, testing, url-encoding, sample-data

Sometimes you need data for tests, like [Adobe Thermo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9IjZJ0D_bo) has prewritten "sets" of data, like 1-word strings, 3-word strings, etc for use in populating data controls.

I need:

- Continuous text, no newlines
- CSV Numbers, Integers
- CSV Numbers, Decimals
- URL encoded strings

Any ideas on how to get any of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GenerateData.com](http://www.generatedata.com/#about) is a free, open source script written in JavaScript, PHP and MySQL that lets you quickly generate large volumes of custom data in a variety of formats for use in testing software, populating databases.

- JS-enabled and browser-friendly.
- Many data types: names, phone numbers, email addresses, cities, states, provinces, counties, dates, street addresses, number ranges, alphanumeric strings, lorem ipsum text and more.
- Option to generate data in XML, Excel, HTML, CSV or SQL.
- Country specific data (state / province / county) for Canada, US, Netherlands and UK.
- Saves your data generation forms for later use

Answer (score 1):

Generate them? A quick perl script can generate huge sets of data.

Part of the challenge with CSV is all the edge cases (awkward standard-use of newlines, which does not exactly match how Excel or SQL Server parse CSVs).  I've had to build those by hand in the past.

Comment: Yup..it's a programming language, like any other.

Answer (score 1):

> Continuous text, no newlines

Download a few files from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) and run sed on it to replace newlines by whitespace.

> CSV Numbers, Integers

Google/Y! finance AFAIK allows you to download historical stock quotes. That'd be a nice start. But they are usually a mixture of string(stock name), date and 4 different floating values and one integral volume value.

Answer (score 1):

I simply made (in VB.NET) a helper class to generate random strings of a length in a specified range, or random numbers. I did this when first trying unit testing within Visual Studio. So, for example, when I wanted to test Customer.Create, I would set up a loop to run 1000 times to create 1000 customers with all kinds of random values. For example,

(pseudo-real-code)

```
For x = 1 to 1000
    Dim c as New Customer
    c.Name = Helpers.GetRandomString([minLenth], [maxLength])
    c.Address1 = Helpers.GetRandomString([minLenth], [maxLength])
    c.Telephone = Helpers.GetRandomPhoneNumber()
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.mockaroo.com](http://www.mockaroo.com).

This is  a free tool that let's you generate up to 100,000 rows of realistic test data in CSV, tab-delimited, and SQL formats. You can generate just about any data type: strings, numbers, emails, domains, urls, addresses, names, unicode, custom values based on a formula you provide and a lot more. You can also save your schemas for reuse.

Comment: FYI, If you're looking specifically for a set of URLs to test with -- as I was -- the Mockaroo site is better.  Unlike GenerateData.com, it has a specific 'url' data type.  You can even customize the URL features to generate.